# Angular - Jasmine: Testing immediately invoked functions inside a directive controller

Tags: angularjs, testing, angularjs-directive, jasmine, spy

Suppose that I have a directive like:

```
.directive('myDir', function(TemplateHandler){
  return {
    ...
    controller: function(ExploreCmd){
      this.foo = {
        bar: function(){...}
      };

      this.foo.bar();
    }
  }
});
```

And I want to test that when the directive is loaded the `this.foo.bar()` function has been called, how can I achieve that?

I tried with:

```
beforeEach(inject(function($compile, $rootScope){
  scope = $rootScope.$new();
  element = angular.element('<js-shell></js-shell>');
  $compile(element)(scope);
  scope.$digest();
  isolatedScope = element.isolateScope().vm;
  spyOn(isolatedScope.foo, 'bar');
}));

it('should register the explore command', () => {
  expect(isolatedScope.foo.bar).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

But the problem is that `spyOn(isolatedScope.foo, 'bar');` is called after the `isolatedScope.foo.bar` has been called, so the test fail.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can in this situation. There is no moment in time between when foo is created and when foo.bar is invoked where you could get hold of it to replace foo.bar with a spy.

By the time your spyOn function runs, foo.bar() has been called and returned.

If foo.bar has a side effect like setting foo.baz to true, you can look at that.

Comment: Thanks Amy, that was my same feeling. I'll go down the way to check side effects. Another option that came into my mind is to move `foo.bar` in a service an have the function in the component calling that one so that I can mock/spy on it...

Comment: Or call it later in response to some other happening.